# Is there a way of splitting a C# generic dictionary into multiple dictionaries?

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, split

I have a C# dictionary `Dictionary<MyKey, MyValue>` and I want to split this into a collection of `Dictionary<MyKey, MyValue>`, based on `MyKey.KeyType`. `KeyType` is an enumeration.

Then I would be left with a dictionary containing key-value pairs where `MyKey.KeyType = 1`, and another dictionary where `MyKey.KeyType = 2`, and so on.

Is there a nice way of doing this, such as using Linq?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var dictionaryList = 
    myDic.GroupBy(pair => pair.Key.KeyType)
         .OrderBy(gr => gr.Key)  // sorts the resulting list by "KeyType"
         .Select(gr => gr.ToDictionary(item => item.Key, item => item.Value))
         .ToList(); // Get a list of dictionaries out of that
```

If you want a dictionary of dictionaries keyed by "KeyType" in the end, the approach is similar:

```
var dictionaryOfDictionaries = 
    myDic.GroupBy(pair => pair.Key.KeyType)
         .ToDictionary(gr => gr.Key,         // key of the outer dictionary
             gr => gr.ToDictionary(item => item.Key,  // key of inner dictionary
                                   item => item.Value)); // value
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following will work?

```
dictionary
    .GroupBy(pair => pair.Key.KeyType)
    .Select(group => group.ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

So you're actually wanting a variable of type `IDictionary<MyKey, IList<MyValue>>`?

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the GroupBy Linq function:

```
            var dict = new Dictionary<Key, string>
                   {
                       { new Key { KeyType = KeyTypes.KeyTypeA }, "keytype A" },
                       { new Key { KeyType = KeyTypes.KeyTypeB }, "keytype B" },
                       { new Key { KeyType = KeyTypes.KeyTypeC }, "keytype C" }
                   };

        var groupedDict = dict.GroupBy(kvp => kvp.Key.KeyType);

        foreach(var item in groupedDict)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Grouping for: {0}", item.Key);
            foreach(var d in item)
                Console.WriteLine(d.Value);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you just want to have separate collections:

```
Dictionary myKeyTypeColl<KeyType, Dictionary<MyKey, KeyVal>>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Dictionary <int,string> sports;
sports=new Dictionary<int,string>();
sports.add(0,"Cricket");
sports.add(1,"Hockey");
sports.add(2,"Badminton");
sports.add(3,"Tennis");
sports.add(4,"Chess");
sports.add(5,"Football");
foreach(var spr in sports)
console.WriteLine("Keu {0} and value {1}",spr.key,spr.value);
```

output:

```
Key 0 and value Cricket
Key 1 and value Hockey
Key 2 and value Badminton
Key 3 and value Tennis
Key 4 and value Chess
Key 5 and value Football
```