# Split dictionary into multiple equal sized dictionaries

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, split

I have a `Dictionary` shown below. Say there are 400 elements in the `Dictionary` I want to split this `Dictionary` into 4 equal sized dictionaries. How do I do this? With list there is a range method that I can use however not sure what to do here?

I do not care how the `Dictionary` is split just so that they are equally sized.

```
Dictionary<string, CompanyDetails> coDic;
```

Comment: What if there are 401 items?

Comment: that's fine, have 3 dictionaries with 100 and 1 with 101. I'm more interested in how to split a dictionary

Comment: What do you want to do with the split dictionnary? If you are concerned about performance or load baancing, there are specialized collections that will do the job for you

Comment: var newDict = coDic.Skip(0).Take(100).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way of splitting a C# generic dictionary into multiple dictionaries?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177667/is-there-a-way-of-splitting-a-c-sharp-generic-dictionary-into-multiple-dictionar)

Comment: @PPC I have the issue with performance. What are those specialized collections?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use a simple modulus to group the dictionary in parts:

```
int numberOfGroups = 4;
int counter = 0;

var result = dict.GroupBy(x => counter++ % numberOfGroups);
```

The modulus (`%`) makes the `GroupBy` to be restricted to a number in the range `0..3` (actually `0..numberOfGroups - 1`). This will make the grouping for you.

A problem though with this one is that it doesn't preserve the order. This one does:

```
decimal numberOfGroups = 4;
int counter = 0;
int groupSize = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(dict.Count / numberOfGroups));

var result = dict.GroupBy(x => counter++ / groupSize);
```

Comment: Could have something like: `.Select(g => g.ToDictionary(h => h.Key, h => h.Value))` on the end to have dictionaries in `result`.

Comment: I don't understand why one would care about order in dictionaries? as when enumerating a dictionary ["The order in which the items are returned is undefined."](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)

Comment: @weston indeed, but some might find the second implementation useful. 'for the sake of completeness'.

Comment: Fair enough, I'd say if keeping stuff together is important, they should probably `OrderBy` first before grouping.

Answer (score 4):

I would use the following query:

```
Dictionary<string, CompanyDetails>[] result =
    dict
        .Select((kvp, n) => new { kvp, k = n % 4 })
        .GroupBy(x => x.k, x => x.kvp)
        .Select(x => x.ToDictionary(y => y.Key, y => y.Value))
        .ToArray();
```

The advantage here is the avoidance of closing over a counter as the `.Select((kvp, n) => ...)` statement has a counter built-in.

Answer (score 3):

I combined posts in this code. The result is an `IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, string>>` to use in a `foreach` for example.

```
int counter = 0;
int groupSize = 5;
IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, string>> result = info
    .GroupBy(x => counter++ / groupSize)
    .Select(g => g.ToDictionary(h => h.Key, h => h.Value));

foreach (Dictionary<string, string> rsl in result) {
    // your code
}
```